# REST API ошибка при получении, передаче данных

Tags: node.js, express

Делаю REST API на node.js + express.js
У меня сразу 2 вопроса.

```
server.js
var express = require('express');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var app = express();
//Routes
app.use('/users', users);
_______________________________________
/routes/users.js
var express     = require('express');
var user = require('../app/models/user');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/users', function (req, res) {
  models.User.findAll()
    .then(function (users) {
    res.json(users);
  })
});
module.exports = router;
______________________________________
/models/user.js
module.exports = function(sequelize, Data) {
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    firstname: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    role: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
  });
  return User;
}
```

Вопрос первый это ошибка когда делаю запрос на http://localhost:3000/users/users

```
ReferenceError: models is not defined
at /home/sergei/Документы/NodeJSProjects/ParkingHouse/routes/users.js:7:5
GET /users/users 500
```

А вопрос второй как изменить роутинг чтобы по адресам ссылаться на:

http://localhost:3000/api/users ссылаться на /routes/users.js

http://localhost:3000/api/cars ссылаться на /routes/cars.js

не пробовал конечно, но полагаю, что такой вариант не пройдет

```
//Routes
app.use('/api', users);
app.use('/api', cars);
```

Comment: 1. В `/routes/users.js` переменная `models` - не определена, отсюда и ошибка. 2. Вариант с `app.use('/api', users);` сработает

Comment: А не могли бы вы на пальцах объяснить откуда берется эта модель. Я уже каких только примеров не посмотрел, вот тут хоть как то похоже на то что мне надо https://github.com/sequelize/express-example